# MVC 4 Capitalized controller in route returns 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We get a 404 page not found error when we request this url on our production server "/Account/Login", but "/account/Login" works just fine. Only the case of the first letter of the controller differs.

Also, we do not have this problem on our development server.

The problem just appeared in the last days but we didn't see any change in our route configurations. So I have no idea what can cause that problem.

Here is the RouteConfig.cs code if you see something that could explain:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MobileWebsite.App_Start
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            if (routes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");

            const string defautlRouteUrl = "{controller}/{action}/{id}";
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            RouteValueDictionary defaultRouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

            Route defaultRoute = new Route(defautlRouteUrl, defaultRouteValueDictionary, new MvcRouteHandler());
            routes.Add("DefaultGlobalisedClientSiteLang", new GlobalisedRouteClientSiteLang(defaultRoute.Url, defaultRoute.Defaults));
            routes.Add("DefaultGlobalisedClientSite", new GlobalisedRouteClientSite(defaultRoute.Url, defaultRoute.Defaults));
            routes.Add("DefaultGlobalised", new GlobalisedRoute(defaultRoute.Url, defaultRoute.Defaults));
            routes.Add("Default", new Route(defautlRouteUrl, defaultRouteValueDictionary, new MvcRouteHandler()));          
        }
    }

    public class GlobalisedRoute : Route
    {
        public const string CultureKey = "culture";
        static string CreateCultureRoute(string unGlobalisedUrl)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{" + CultureKey + "}}/{0}", unGlobalisedUrl);
        }
        public GlobalisedRoute(string unGlobalisedUrl, RouteValueDictionary defaults) : 
            base(CreateCultureRoute(unGlobalisedUrl),
               defaults,
               new RouteValueDictionary(new { culture = new CultureRouteConstraint() }),
               new GlobalisationRouteHandler())
        {
        }
    }
    public class GlobalisedRouteClientSiteLang : Route
    {
        public const string CultureKey = "culture";
        public const string ClientSiteIdKey = "clientSiteId";
        static string CreateClientSiteRoute(string unGlobalisedUrl)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{" + ClientSiteIdKey + "}}/{{" + CultureKey + "}}/{0}", unGlobalisedUrl);
        }
        public GlobalisedRouteClientSiteLang(string unGlobalisedUrl, RouteValueDictionary defaults) :
            base(CreateClientSiteRoute(unGlobalisedUrl),
               defaults,
               new RouteValueDictionary(new { culture = new CultureRouteConstraint(), clientSiteId = new ClientSiteIdRouteConstraint() }),
               new GlobalisationRouteHandler())
        {
        }
    }

    public class GlobalisedRouteClientSite : Route
    {
        public const string ClientSiteIdKey = "clientSiteId";
        static string CreateClientSiteRoute(string unGlobalisedUrl)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{" + ClientSiteIdKey + "}}/{0}", unGlobalisedUrl);
        }
        public GlobalisedRouteClientSite(string unGlobalisedUrl, RouteValueDictionary defaults) :
            base(CreateClientSiteRoute(unGlobalisedUrl),
               defaults,
               new RouteValueDictionary(new { clientSiteId = new ClientSiteIdRouteConstraint() }),
               new GlobalisationRouteHandler())
        {
        }
    }

    public class GlobalisationRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
    {
        string CultureValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)RouteDataValues[GlobalisedRoute.CultureKey];
            }
        }

        RouteValueDictionary RouteDataValues
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }

        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");

            RouteDataValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
            CultureManager.SetCulture(CultureValue);
            return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }

    public class CultureRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

            if (!values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
                return false;
            string potentialCultureName = (string)values[parameterName];
            return CultureFormatChecker.FormattedAsCulture(potentialCultureName);
        }
    }

    public class ClientSiteIdRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

            if (!values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
                return false;
            string potentialClientSiteId = (string)values[parameterName];
            return ClientSiteIdFormatChecker.FormattedAsClientSiteId(potentialClientSiteId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the ViewEngine caching mechanism, see explanation here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/09/17/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-caching-bug-fixed.aspx